# jQuery get value of input after changing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problem:

I need to append a field with values of, but the values inside the input field are not recognized or read by JavaScript.

The jQuery "on" method doesn't recognize the values inside the field.

How can I solve this Problem. Clicking on the list items should append to the values inside the input field.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fbLb3k95/1/

JS:

```
$(function(){

$(document).on("click", ".tagSelect a", function(){
    // input field containing values
    if($("input[name='tags']").html() != "")
        tags = $("input[name='tags']").html() + ",";
    else
        tags = "";

    // add new value
    $("input[name='tags']").val(tags + $(this).attr("data"));
});


});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="tags" placeholder="tags" value="" />

<ul id="tagSelect" class="tagSelect">
<li class="row">
    <a class="anchorList back-history-counter" data="monkey">
        <p>monkey</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="row">
    <a class="anchorList back-history-counter" data="elephant">
        <p>elephant</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="row">
    <a class="anchorList back-history-counter" data="lion">
        <p>lion</p>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/fbLb3k95/2/, for get value from input use `val()` instead of `.html`, because `.html`  returns inner HTML but input does not have inner html ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use val() method instead of html():

```
$(function(){

$(document).on("click", ".tagSelect a", function(){
    // input field containing values
    if($("input[name='tags']").val() != "")
        tags = $("input[name='tags']").val() + ",";
    else
        tags = "";

    // add new value
    $("input[name='tags']").val(tags + $(this).attr("data"));
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly revised version that puts tags into array so that trailing commas won't get left when you start removing tags

```
var tagDelimiter = ', ';
$(document).on("click", ".tagSelect a", function () {
    var $tagInput = $("input[name='tags']"),
        newTag = $(this).attr("data"),
        tagVal = $tagInput.val(),
        tagsArr = tagVal ? tagVal.split(tagDelimiter) : [];

    tagsArr.push(newTag);
    $tagInput.val(tagsArr.join(tagDelimiter));
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fbLb3k95/4/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Alright so a few things, and this is mainly to help with good practices rather than merely solve the answer(as @BhojendraNepal has done well). Lets start with the final code:

```
var $tagsInput = $('input').filter('[name="tags"]');

$('.tagSelect').on({
    click:function(){
        var data = $(this).attr('data'),
            tags;

        if($tagsInput.val()){
            tags = $tagsInput.val() + ',';
        } else {
            tags = '';
        }

        $tagsInput.trigger('tagChange',[tags,data]);
    }
},'a');

$tagsInput.on({
    tagChange:function(e,tags,data){
        $tagsInput.val(tags + data);
    }
});
```

A couple things to note:

- The item you reference multiple times is cached
- The `.on('click')` uses the closest parent as delegation driver, rather than the `document`
- The change of the `input` value has been modified to take place in its own event structure, rather than within the `click` event

**Why would you do all that?**

If you reference something multiple times, you should cache it because jQuery would otherwise need to re-query the DOM. Querying the DOM is the most taxing part of JavaScript, so minimizing this is the key to performant JavaScript.

Using event delegation helps out for a number of reasons, however your use of delegating from the top-level `document` is the least performant way to do this (even the jQuery documentation says to avoid this in their [`.on()` documentation under event performance](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). The ideal scenario is to use the closest-scoped parent as possible, and luckily you have identified one in the `.tagSelect` class. Using that as your delegation driver will provide the same benefits, but even better performance.

The segregation of the `value` change is a bit more abstract, but useful to understand if you ever plan this application to get larger. Perhaps you will want something else to cause the value change in the future, or perhaps your click functionality will grow to be massive, who knows. By separating the click functionality (setting the value for `tags`) from how it affects the `input` (changing the `value`), you are creating a more extensible code methodology that is separated by concerns. I'm sure I'll get some people saying "it doesn't matter for an application of this size", but its a good methodology to get familiar with because it can save many headaches in the future.

Just my two cents. As mentioned, @BhojendraNepal's answer works just fine because your issue was using `.html()` instead of `.val()`, just providing some extra info.

Comment: OP is already using delegation and there is only one event handler being bound for all the `a` tags. No idea what you are talking about with `multiple` handlers

Comment: yeah sorry ... he is using event delegation, just in the least performant way possible. even the jQuery documentation says to avoid delegating from the `document`, so I'll modify my verbiage to reflect this. appreciate the catch.

Comment: well that wipes out about 1/2 of your answer

Comment: @charlietfl - no, just changes it. its still a performance benefit that needs to be taken into account. not sure i understand the hostility, it appears by ur answer we are both trying to assist in performance, just from different angles.